# Can I keep a certain functions from being inherited in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Sample code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Func()
    {
        cout << "\nIn base func";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void Func()
    {
        cout << "\nIn derived";
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Derived
{
public:
    void Func()
    {
        cout << "\nIn derived2";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* lnewbase = new Derived2();

    lnewbase->Func();

    return 0;
}
```

As an example, in the above code, I do not want Func() of Derived to be inherited (seal in C#) which is why there is no virtual keyword although I am aware that it does not change anything in this case. Is there any way to disallow that function to be inherited while making sure it remains a public method?

Comment: I think your use of "inherited" is misleading -- rather, I would say "Can I keep a certain functions from being overloaded in C++".  Saying "inherited" makes me think that you want the function to not be accessible for instances of the subclass (which you could accomplish by declaring it as private in the subclass).

Comment: This is a dangerous edit and is substantially different from the original question asked by the OP. I don't think you can assume that the OP means "override" when he says "inherited", even if the answer to the latter is "No, that is not possible." The analogy to `sealed` may be misleading as the OP may simply be misinterpreting what `sealed` actually does in this case.

Comment: @Edward: I don't think it is misleading. To quote you `I want the function to not be accessible by instance of subclasses`, but I cannot make it private because then clients would not be able to access it. And correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't `overload` carry a completely different meaning than `inherited` or `over-ridden`?

Comment: You want everyone to be able to call the function, except the subclass? If it is public, it **is** public.

Comment: @Bo: The subclass may call it, just not inherit it.

Comment: @Samaursa - If it is public everyone can see it, especially the subclass. Your best bet is to add to the documentation "Do not override this function!".

Comment: @Edward Loper: Thep proper term is *overriden*, not overloaded. Overloading is providing a function identifier with different signatures, overriding is replacing the behavior of a virtual function in a base class by implementing it in a derived class with exactly the same signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; C++ has no equivalent to C#'s `sealed` modifier.

Comment: C++03 doesn't, but C++11 has the `final` member-function-decorator that is directly analogous to C# and C++/CLI's `sealed`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do.

Once you make a function in a base class virtual, there's nothing that can be done to get rid of that aspect of it. I can only think of a few things to almost get around it:

- Don't make it virtual;
- Make a new, public, non-virtual function in `Derived` that does what you need.

However, in either case, `Derived2` will still be able to make its own version of `Func()`, which will give you the same problem.